# output both stderr and stdout to file, and only stderr to command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line

When my batch script runs, I want any errors to show up on the command prompt, so the user sees it straight away, while suppressing all the standard output that shows up.

But I want everything to be outputted to a log file. How do I do this?

In other words,

```
+---------+
|         | --- stderr ---------> Console
| Program |
|         | --- stdout/err -----> Log file
+---------+
```

Comment: how do you differentiate `error` and `garbage`?  `1>a.log 2>&1` -- will redirect both output and errors to a.out. If you just want errors to log use `2>a.out`.

Comment: Stuff that goes to stdout.

Comment: @Bill - but the problem with that solution, is that stderr won't display on the command prompt.

Comment: oh, you want both..i see, sorry

Comment: look at this -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11879085/redirect-stderr-to-console-and-file

Comment: @Bill does that answer, of linux + bash, work with windows' command prompt, which is what it looks like they are asking about?

Comment: my bad, i must be reading a lot between lines..you are windows, not unix, sorry...`stderr` automatically directed me towards `unix`...sorry again.

Comment: let me know if this is what you want - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149436/redirect-error-stream-to-file-and-console-in-windows

Comment: Standard garbage? I know of no `stdgrb` file handle :-) Changed to standard output for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo  I wish there was +1 for edits...the diagram is very helpful.

Comment: @Bill, if it makes the question more useful, upvote the question. It's not as if I _need_ any more rep :-) I'll never catch Skeet but I'm comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

There are various versions of `tee` that can be downloaded (or created using VBS or JScript), and you could redirect stderr to stdout and pipe everything through tee. But then you would get both stdout and stderr to both the console and the file.

I believe it is impossible to send both to a file, yet selectively send stderr to the console, unless there is something special in the content of all errors that could be used to identify an error. I doubt there is a consistent unique identifier for errors, but if there is, the solution could look something like this:

```
yourScript 2>&1 | tee output.log | find "Error:"
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have `tee`:

```
yourScript 2>&1 > output.log & type output.log | find "Error:"
```

Comment: This was useful. For extra credit, how would you send the output of the find step back to stderr? Is that just an additional `>$2` on the end?

Comment: @mjs I forgot how redirecting standard input/errors work. If it works per program, I'd guess `find 2> "qwerty"`. Really, though, we have PowerShell now.

Comment: Excellent answer, simplicity with less dependencies is highly valuable!