# Duplicating stderr output and merge with stderr in bash without changing order

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, bash-scripting, pipe

I want to write both stderr and stdout to a log file, and print stderr to the terminal (or default output device).

**Motivation:** I have a command in my crontab, and I want to log all of its output to a file, and I want cron to e-mail me if there is something written to the error output.

I had some success with these:

```
(echo out1; echo err1 1>&2; echo out2; echo err2 1>&2) \
    2> >(tee -a log) \
    1>>log
```

Or:

```
(echo err1 1>&2; echo out2; echo err2 1>&2) \
    3>&1 \
    1> >(tee -a log 1>/dev/null) \
    2> >(tee -a log 1>&3)
```

Or with exec:

```
exec 3>&1
exec 1> >(tee -a log2 1>/dev/null)
exec 2> >(tee -a log2 1>&3)
echo out1; echo err1 1>&2; echo out2; echo err2 1>&2
```

(The third solution also logs the prompt, so it doesn't work in an interactive shell.)

The problem with all three solutions is that the log file contains the lines in a different order:

```
out1
out2
err1
err2
```

Instead of this:

```
out1
err1
out2
err2
```

Is there a way to prevent this? Something like `2>&1`, that duplicates the output itself, and not the descriptor.

There is a very similar [question](https://superuser.com/questions/599354/output-both-stderr-and-stdout-to-file-and-only-stderr-to-command-prompt) for Windows

Comment: Duplicate on U&L: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79996/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-and-display-stderr-to-console.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I haven't found that. I can't flag the question as duplicate, because the other question is on a different domain, what should I do? By the way, it's somewhat surprising to me that there is no clean solution for something like this

Comment: You didn't post that one, so it's not cross-posting. No worries then. Just leave it as it is. As for the matter in question, it's not as surprising as it may seem. It's simplicity. STDERR and STDOUT are two different channels and synchronising them would introduce costs. You may think of a way how to go about them not being synchronised or checking in the common log for a sign of error with `grep` or something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to simplify and optimise this as far as possible. I can't think now of any better solution than taking it step by step. Namely,

```
$ echo out1 >> log
$ echo err1 | tee -a log >&2
err1
$ echo out2 >> log
$ echo err2 | tee -a log >&2
err2
$ cat log
out1
err1
out2
err2
```

Well, you might use a coprocess, so that you'd not need to call tee many times if that matters to you.

```
$ coproc tee -a log
[1] 26417
$ echo out1 >> log
$ echo err1 >&"${COPROC[1]}"
$ echo out2 >> log
$ echo err2 >&"${COPROC[1]}"
$ cat log
out1
err1
out2
err2
```

Now whatever errors there have been, they're waiting in the coprocess' output pipe. If you just need to check if there's anything there, this will do:

```
$ timeout 1 head -n1 <&"${COPROC[0]}" >/dev/null && echo yes # or something else
yes
```

If you want to reuse the errors, then you might want to modify the coprocess to suit your aim.

You can set redirection for scripts and binaries as well. As long as they don't have hard-wired redirections themselves, of course. Thus you can do this,

```
$ some_executable 2>&"${COPROC[1]}" >>log
```

And the logic stays the same.

Comment: This works and is easy to do, but the echo commands are just examples, I want to use the redirection with installed 3rd-party scripts and binaries, they would be rather cumbersome to modify this way. 
I didn't know `coproc`, it makes the code nicer, but doesn't seem to solve the problem above.

Comment: @TPE It doesn't matter. I've appended an explanation.

Comment: ''You can set redirection for scripts and binaries as well'' I don't think that works, if the executable write to both stdout and stderr in a certain order, they still get mixed up.

Comment: @TPE Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes, I copied the echo commands into an `.sh` script, and also tried a simple C program with outputs like this: `write(2, "err1\n", 5);`

Comment: @TPE Ok. Then it's not so easy. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79996/how-to-redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-file-and-display-stderr-to-console